# Improper integral with two infinite bounds

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

How can I solve:

$\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{1}{y^2+1} dy$

I have tried splitting it up in two limits:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} [arctan(y)]^n_0 + \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} [arctan(y)]^0_n$

But now I'm stuck, can someone help me out?

Comment: Why $\arctan(y^2)$, not $\arctan(y)$?

Comment: @Jakubussimus Because I'm wrong, thank you. :) But I still don't know where to go from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe the integrand is an even function, thus: $I = 2\displaystyle \int_{0}^\infty \dfrac{dy}{1+y^2} = 2\tan^{-1} y|_{y=0}^\infty = \pi$

Comment: How is $2tan^{−1}y|^∞_{y=0}=π$ ?

Comment: @Michiel The statement that $2\tan^{-1} y|_{y=0}^\infty = \pi$ is just a loose way to say that $\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}2\tan^{-1} y|_{y=0}^b = \pi$, which is a pretty basic property of the $arctan$ function - just take a look at [its graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+arctan%28x%29)